# How to download data from mysql connection

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pandas, database-connection

After making a connection with mysql library, i'd like to dowload all the database from the connection in my local space (tranforming them into pandas dataframe).

Here's my code:

```
    import MySQLdb
    import pandas as pd

    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='host' , user='datbase', passwd='password', db='databases' )
cursor = conn.cursor()

query = cursor.execute('  SELECT *  FROM pro ')

df = pd.read_sql(query , conn)

row = cursor.fetchone()

conn.close()
```

I finnaly got the connection, so i can make some query. But i'd like to use these sql database as a pandas dataframe, '''how can i do it'''?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
query = '  SELECT *  FROM pro '
df = pd.read_sql(query , conn)
```

And `df` should already be your desired dataframe.